# ¿Cual es la diferencia entra HttpPost y HttpGet en MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, post

¿Qué diferencia existe entre el uso de `[HttpGet]` y `[HttPost]`, cuándo debe usarse uno y cuando el otro?

Comment: Disculpa, a que haces referencia cuando preguntas por desempeño, para que sirve cada función?

Comment: Me refiero que fin tiene o para que se utiliza...y si cada una de esas 2 funciones...@Pedro Miguel Pimienta Morales

Comment: El título de la pregunta no concuerda con su contenido, primero preguntas cuál la función de cada verbo y luego preguntas por el desempeño, ¿a cuál te refieres exactamente, función o desempeño?

Comment: Osea que rol cumplen esos dos....

Comment: @Flxtr ya corregi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno entendiendo tu pregunta, acerca del uso y la diferencia entre **POST** Y **GET**, que fue lo que vi desde un principio cuando vi tu pregunta.

En el caso del método POST, el cual se usa para realizar una petición a un servidor enviando información, y sea para insertar o consultar algo y esperar una respuesta luego de finalizada la operación recibir algún tipo de mensaje o información. Por ejemplo yo utilizo el **POST** para poder iniciar sesion en una aplicacion móvil, envío el usuario y la contraseña a un servidor esperando la respuesta si existe el usuario y la contraseña.

En el caso del **GET** se usa para obtener información, por ejemplo si lo que vas hacer es enviar una array de información luego de haber actualizado algo del lado del servidor, por ejemplo, cuando luego de conectarte a tu teléfono te llegan mensajes sin necesidad de enviar algún tipo de informacion.

Answer (score 1):

Es un atributo cuya finalidad es establecer la forma en que la acción puede ser accedida; es decir si usas el que tiene GET solo "lo encontrara" cuando el método de llamada fue GET;para el caso del POST es similar cuando la invocación de una acción sea por POST.

Ejemplo si tienes en tu `Controller`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Mifuncion() {
  // Tu código
}
```

usando Ajax te devolver error si usas:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "ruta/Mifuncion",
   method : 'GET',
   /* TU DEMÁS CÓDIGO */
}
);
```

caso contrario (será exitosa) si lo realizas de la siguiente forma:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "ruta/Mifuncion",
   method : 'POST',
   /* TU DEMÁS CÓDIGO */
}
);
```

concluira de forma exitosa.

Comment: Gracias. @Roberto León Orames..

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a las diferencias entre uno y otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Información extraída de [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

¿En qué momento deberás usar uno u otro? Depende del objetivo de tu prueba, pero si te basas en la tabla anterior seguramente siempre vas a elegir el método correcto.